# What compiled versions of an Access database don't require the user to have Access?

Tags: vba, ms-office

I know that there are several options for compiling and Access database to get around user tampering. I believe there is an option that would allow me to deploy the compiled Access database to a workstation that does not have Access even installed. Please advise.

Thanks!